# jQuery - Selecting children by class using parents ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using the [MCustomScrollBar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller), but have multiple instances of the scrollbar on the page. I need to be able to target `.mCSB_container` to append `<li>`elements dynamically to each of the scrollbars separately.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779312/how-do-i-dynamically-find-out-what-the-id-or-class-of-a-div) is the same question essentially, but the accepted answer won't work, as it's trying to get the id using `attr`, where the class doesn't have an id.

```
<div id="titles" class="scroll-box" style="opacity: 1;">

    <h2>Latest Titles</h2>
    <ul class="scroll-horizontal mCustomScrollbar _mCS_1">
        <div class="mCustomScrollBox mCSB_horizontal" id="mCSB_1" style="position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden; max-width:100%;">
            <div class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; left: 0px; width: 2860px;">
                <li class="product-car"> My Car</li>
                <li class="product-bike"> My Bike </li>
                <li class="product-tree"> My Tree </li>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </ul>

</div>

<div id="titles" class="scroll-box" style="opacity: 1;">

    <h2>Latest Houses</h2>
    <ul class="scroll-horizontal mCustomScrollbar _mCS_2">
        <div class="mCustomScrollBox mCSB_horizontal" id="mCSB_2" style="position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden; max-width:100%;">
            <div class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; left: 0px; width: 2860px;">
                <li class="product-house"> My House</li>
                <li class="product-boat"> My Boat </li>
                <li class="product-tree"> My Tree </li>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </ul>

</div>
```

So I've tried playing around using [jQuery children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) but to no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To append to your first scrollbar locate it by the id `#mCSB_1` and use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `>` to get to your desired container, like so:

```
$('#mCSB_1 > .mCSB_container').append('<li class="product-tree"> New LI </li>');
```

and for your second scrollbar do the same but for id `#mCSB_2`:

```
$('#mCSB_2 > .mCSB_container').append('<li class="product-tree"> New LI </li>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is essentially what I did .